# Dict with object-like __getattr__ but

Tags: python

I would like to clean up code that heavily uses such class:

```
class ADict(object):
  pass
#example usage
a = ADict()
a.attr = 1
```

What I'd like to do is keep the `__getattr__` notation, but add a constructor argument that is a list of allowed ADict keys, which are also checked in `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`. Apart from whether it's a good idea, is it doable? How? Here's my failed attempt (doesn't work because of infinite recursion):

```
class ADict(object):

  def __init__(self, keys):
    object.__init__(self)
    self.keys = keys

  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    print('hi1')
    if attr not in object.__getattribute__(self.keys):
      raise KeyError()
    return object.__getattr__(self, attr)

  def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    print('hi2')
    if attr not in object.__getattribute__(self.keys):
      raise KeyError()
    return object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)

a = ADict(['a'])
a.b = 2
```

Comment: `if attr not in object.__getattribute__(self.keys):` - why not just `if attr not in self.keys`? Could you provide a [mcve] that includes the traceback?

Comment: try `namedtuple`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: the traceback just says that there's a recursion limit reached. I was trying to avoid writing "self.keys", though now I see I did it anyway.

Comment: @shx2 Good idea, but it doesn't let me change the keys later.

Comment: Why were you trying to avoid `self.keys`? That's literally the attribute you have set.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the **slots** magic variable. Basically, if you define it you are restricting the attributes that a given object can have:

```
class ADict:
    __slots__ = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

a = ADict()
a.foo = 1             # this will work

a.another_thing = 1   # this will throw an AttributeError
```

However, have a good look at the documentation before implementing this, as it is usually not a good idea unless you are having very strict memory requirements for your application.

Comment: Just to emphasize, `__slots__` is intented to be used to save memory, and has some caveats. For example you cannot use the common idiom of a class variable to give default values to instance variables if the class uses `__slots__`. Be sure to read the doc before using it.

Comment: @SergeBallesta: this only works in Py2 on my laptop.